# Is there anyway to do an asynchronous FindNextFile?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, ntfs

On a large folder (~300,000 objects) FindNextFile can take up to 20 secs to respond with just a single file. I assume there's some bulk operation going on in the background but it makes the operation very difficult to cancel.

Is there a way to run FindNextFile in an asynchronous mode so that it can be cancelled if the information is no longer required?

Win7, x64, NTFS.

Side note: Once the information has been cached by Windows FindNextFile doesn't appear to have this issue. It's only on the first time it tries to enumerate files in a large folder.

Comment: You invoke FindNextFile in a loop, correct?  Why not just put the loop in a thread (and allow the user to cancel)?  PS: I'm not aware of any Win32-level caching, except for SMB file shares.

Comment: Have you tried using CancelSynchronousIo?

Comment: @paulsm4 FindNextFile does issue batch queries: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/04/07/570801.aspx

snowdude: How much information do you want from each file?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 I need most of the WIN32_FIND_DATA, but not cAlternateFileName.

Comment: Then FindNextFile is the right choice if you have a cache size around or larger than 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, FindNextFile is synchronous and there's no asynchronous function that's comparable.  The usual solution to this sort of problem is multithreading.  You need two threads: a UI thread that should always remain responsive to the user and a worker thread that does the FindNextFile calls.  I would use a queue with a locking mechanism.  The logic would look something like this:

Worker Thread:

```
FindFirstFile();
do
{
    LockQueue();
    AddFileToQueue();
    UnlockQueue();
 while (FindNextFile() && !UserCanceled());
 SetAllFilesDone();
```

UI Thread:

```
while (!UserCanceled() && !AllFilesDone())
{
    LockQueue();
    GetFileFromQueue();
    UnlockQueue();
    ProcessFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IShellFolder::EnumObjects is a faster query if you just need to access a few files, but [slower on a network](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/30/564809.aspx) as FindNextFile's batch io has less network roundtrips. Whether you use it or not depends on how much information you need, and the latency of each file.

Comment: IShellFolder::EnumObjects is a usermode shell extension: How does it perform the equivalent of FindNextFile without calling FindNextFile?

Comment: It issues a different kind of query, one that returns the pidl only, for getting attributes you need additional calls to IShellFolder, like IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf. If you plan to skip most of the files in the query (e.g. when you are doing paging) then IShellFolder::EnumObjects can be a faster query.